# How can I cause my Ant build to fail if my Groovy task fails?

Tags: ant, groovy

I expected that if the script in the `<groovy>` tags returned false or non-zero then the Ant task would fail but it is not the case. Got old Groovy if that makes a difference (1.8.6).

Comment: Did you try to throw a groovy exception? That should fail the task.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean any old Java exception or specifically a `GroovyException`? I tried a `RuntimeException` and yes, that fails the task. It's a shame I have to see the stack trace on the console though.

Comment: Curiously it seems that the Groovy task handles some exceptions differently. For example, an `IOException` causes the task to fail without printing a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an exception will cause ANT to fail. A cleaner way to do it would be to set a property within the script as follows:

```
  <target name="build">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

    <groovy>
      properties["groovy.error"] = true
    </groovy>

    <fail message="Fail baby fail" if="groovy.error"/>
  </target>
```

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that you might need:`<fail message="Fail baby fail" if="${groovy.error}"/>` because otherwise the fail task fails if the property is defined, i.e. even if it is false.

Comment: @Tom Yes. "true" could be any value.